# Why is there no badge/tag that can be achieved for hibernate/nhibernate

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges

On Stackoverflow, I see that you can achieve badges and tags.
For instance, when you've received 400 upvotes for answers that have been posted in questions with the C# tag, you receive a badge for this.
This is also true for answers in questions that have been tagged with sql, jquery, .net, etc...

My question is: why is it not possible to achieve an nhibernate/hibernate badge ?

Comment: By the way, you need about 320+ more upvotes in the nhibernate tag for your silver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Badges only register once someone reaches 400 upvotes. If no NHibernate badge exist, it simply means that no one has reached 400 upvotes on the nhibernate tag yet.

To confirm that badges indeed correctly register, look at the fact that there is a badge for the "[string](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/87/string)" tag...

Answer (score 6):

Baseline right now for a silver badge is **400** upvotes on a tag.

> [image: this is not 300?]

So you'll need about one hundred more on the **`[hibernate]`** tag to see if it clocks you in one or not.

Comment: I don't know how many upvotes in nhibernate/hibernate i have, and I'm also not really interested in that, but, I just asked myself the question as I was scrolling through the badges that can be achieved.
I saw C#, sql, etc... badges, but no nhibernate badge.

Comment: You'll need to score at least 400 upvotes in the tag before seeing if you can badge up.

Comment: random, I hate you! Put in a comment next time, so I can defer my upvote. Feel my pain not being able to honour such nice paintings. Ok, enough complaints. - This is META!

Comment: When the mood to Paint strikes, it just hits, and there's no forewarning.

Comment: *sigh* Artists, they don't take advice...

Comment: So somebody else caught 300 on TNT the other night, eh?

Comment: No TNT down here in Australia.

Comment: 5555 - make a screen shot, random!

Comment: Shot taken, but just waiting to artsy it up.

Comment: The actual PNG of the image isn't that blurry if you view it directly.