# What are the rules for creation of tag-specific badges?

Tags: support, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Tag-specific badges can be awarded by getting enough upvotes on answers to enough questions with the said tag (e.g. 100 upvotes on at least 20 answers for the bronze badge). But for the badge to be awarded, it must already *exist*.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22136/why-is-there-no-badge-tag-that-can-be-achieved-for-hibernate-nhibernate/22138#22138) claims that the badge is automatically created once someone achieves 400 upvotes in that badge.

However, on security.SE, the rules seem different. For instance, the [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) badge [exists](https://security.stackexchange.com/badges/72/encryption) but no user [has reached 400 upvotes for it yet](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/encryption/topusers). Conversely, the [hash](/questions/tagged/hash) badge does not exist yet on security.SE, because otherwise I would already have it (237 upvotes on 24 questions). Also, security.SE graduated out of beta recently, so maybe things are different in beta sites.

So, what are the complete rules for specialist badge creation ?

Comment: All you want can be found in [the Badge list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), specifically [the tag badges post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395). Pay note that your cited answer predates the existence of bronze badges, whilst hash doesn't exist because there are only 55 questions in total for that tag (there must be at least 100 questions with that tag, which I will note is stated on the "Badges" list in the top right, so it's not entirely hidden).

Comment: That should be an answer @Grace, though I'm out of upvotes at the moment...

Comment: @MTibbits I don't really post an answer to a question that I'm voting to close as a duplicate.